# JQuery and HTML Getting the value of a <td> from the every first <tr> of a table to increment it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table which provide data from MySQL server, and I have the inital `tr` contains text boxes to add more. And then append them into the same table.

The problem is that the first `td` of each row should increment.

So If the last `td` value is 5, when I add new row and append it to a new line, it's first `td` value should be 6.

Here is my HTML table:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="after_tr">
        <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center">Diabetes assessment result for patient <?php echo $res[0]['patient_name_en'] ?></th>
       </tr>
       <tr class="bg-info">
         <th>#</th>
         <th>Date Of Assessment</th>
         <th>Assessment Result</th>
         <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Actions</th>
       </tr>
       <?php $i = 1; foreach($res as $result) { if($result['date_of_assessment']!="") { ?>
       <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $i++ ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $result['date_of_assessment'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $result['assessment_result'] ?></td>
         <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete_assessment" id="delete_assessment"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

Here is the table with some data:

[image]

So if I added another line, it should be `2` for the new row.

I tried:

```
console.log($('td:first-child').text())
```

And got an empty result. Then I tried

```
$('tr').parent().siblings(":first").text()
```

And again an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your JS code for actually adding the row looks like, but this is how I would probably do it.

```js
$('#addRow').on('click', function() {
  // get the last tr
  var $lastTr = $('tr').last();
  
  // get the text for the first td of the last tr
  var firstTdText = $lastTr.children('td').first().text();
  
  // try to increment the number
  var newTdText = '-';
  try { newTdText = parseInt(firstTdText) + 1; } catch(e) {}

  var buttonHtml = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete_assessment" name="delete_assessment"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>';

  // create a new tr, append all tds and insert the tr after the last tr
  $('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>').css('text-align','center').text(newTdText))
    .append($('<td>').text('some date'))
    .append($('<td>').text('some number'))
    .append($('<td>').html(buttonHtml))
    .insertAfter($lastTr);
});
```

```css
/* these styles aren't needed of course, but I added this because it all looked a little packed together in this example */
th, td {
  padding: 6px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="after_tr">
    <th colspan="4" style="text-align: center">Diabetes assessment result for patient X</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bg-info">
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Date Of Assessment</th>
    <th>Assessment Result</th>
    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center">1</td>
    <td>2017-07-28</td>
    <td>70</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete_assessment" name="delete_assessment" id="delete_assessment"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addRow">Add row</button>
```

A little extra note. I see that you're using an `id` for the delete button. Make sure that those `id`s are all unique or use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

May be this would be helpful.

Comment: It takes the number `1` and display at the console. But When I added another row, the value at the console is `12` and not `2`

Comment: Maybe we should add the value of the first `td` after the row that have an `id=after_tr` ?

Comment: Anymore help ? I am trying but no results

Comment: try this ``$('tr:last').find('td:first').text()``